Problems with pointers and struct (C++)
Can someone tell me what is wrong with the following code?
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct point{
    int key;
    struct point * key0;
} pnt;

int main() {
    pnt * p = new pnt;
    p->key = 1;
    p->key0->key = 2;
}

I'm kinda new to C++ and I'm still trying to understand these concepts.
I was expecting to be able to set some arbitrary value to the structure I defined. I was just experimenting if I understood how that work.
The compiler just says I used an illegal instruction.

Pointers have to point to something before you use them. key0 in p doesn't point to anything.

It's usually a good idea to provide the compiler/runtime message verbatim, complete with the exact line/circumstance respectively, especially if you're new: it may mean not what you think it means.

The strange thing is that the compiler told me actually nothing, it just didn't return anything

As an aside, you don't have to typedef structs in C++. Just use point as a type.

The strange thing is that the compiler told me actually nothing, -- There is nothing strange about this.  You are responsible for making sure that pointers point somewhere.   C++ isn't a language that does a lot of hand-holding.

The compiler just says I used an illegal instruction. -- It wasn't the compiler that gives the error.  It was the running of your program that gives the error.  Compiling (and linking) succsessfully means that your program was built successfully, and your program was built successfully.  Running the successfully built program is something entirely different.

Why are you doing typedef struct point in C++?

@deomanu01 "The strange thing is that the compiler told me actually nothing" - that is because the compiler only cares that the syntax of the code is correct, not the logic of the code. Your code is "syntactically" correct but "logically" wrong. Logic mistakes don't manifest until runtime. You are getting an runtime error from the OS when you try to access memory you dont own.

In C++, the typedef struct is not needed.  The name of the struct can be used as a type.

You are allocating variables from dynamic memory when they don't need to be.

This line:
pnt * p = new pnt;

Allocates a pnt struct, but does not initialize its contents. The address of the allocated struct is assigned to p.
In this line:
p->key = 1;

You initialize the key field.
But at this point, the key0 field is still uninitialized.
But, in this last line:
p->key0->key = 2;

You attempt to dereference the uninitialized key0 field (with key0->key). This is causing undefined behavior.
To avoid it, you need to initialize key0, either by allocating another pnt struct and using its address, or by using the address of an existing pnt object.
Side notes:

In C++, it is usually better to avoid using raw new.
To begin with, it requires a delete (without it, you get a memory leak - as in your code).
Also, there are better alternatives, like using smart pointers, or in other cases - using standard containers.

It is better to avoid using namespace std;. See here.

In C++, there's no need for typedef to create your struct type (it's common in C). You can simply use:
struct pnt{
    ...
    pnt * key0;
};




Concerning the side notes: smart pointers aren't a magic bullet (although I suspect that they would be appropriate here). More to the point, the whole business with typedef struct and struct point* reeks of C; in C++, struct and class suffice without the typedef, and you can use the names directly without preceding them with a struct keyword.

@JamesKanze I agree smart pointers are not magic bullets, but they can do quite a lot of magic avoiding memory leaks ;-). Regarding the typedef - added a side note.

@wohlstad The real problem here is an uninitialized pointer. In his small example, he got lucky, and it crashed immediately. Initializing the pointer, either by using a smart pointer, or by adding an = nullptr to its declaration, would solve that -- formally, it's still undefined behavior, but in practice, it will result in an immediate crash, from which the debugger can get a valid backtrace. An uninitialized pointer can and often does result in things like the stack getting overwritten, resulting in a crash much later, and the debugger being unable to give a backtrace. Fun.

Your problem is that you never initialise key0, so it's just pointing to random memory.
You need to initialise pointers to point to objects that you've allocated.
